# Partitioning a set of $11$ women and $7$ men - Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> Let $S (n, k)$ be the number of $k$-element partitions of an $n$-element set.
>   A set of **eleven** women and **seven** men is to be partitioned into **four** subsets.
>   None of the subsets should consist exclusively of women or men.
>   How many such partitions are there?

My textbook gives

a) $S(7, 4) · S(11, 4) · 4!$

and

b) $S(7, 4) · (S(10, 3) + 4 · S(10, 4)) · 4!$

as answers, but I don't understand how they arrived at these solutions. Can someone please explain the logical reasoning behind these answers? Thank you for your time.

EDIT: I now realise that b) is just the recursive formula for Stirling numbers (of the second kind) used on a). But how did we arrive at a)? Partitioning $7$ men in $4$ subsets and $11$ women in $4$ subsets should give us 8 subsets(?)

Comment: What's the question for b?

Comment: It's the same question, the two answers are equivalent. @JMP

Comment: How did you get 8?

Comment: If we're using $S(7, 4)$ to partition the men into $4$ subsets and $S(11, 4)$ to partition the women also into $4$ subsets, wouldn't this give us $8$ different subsets? The answers a) and b) are correct, so my reasoning must be flawed, I just don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (a), we first form $4$ subsets consisting of only men and $4$ subsets consisting of only women. Now, think of each subset of men *merging* with one subset of women, so that all $8$ subsets get paired to form $4$ subsets, none of which exclusively consist of all men/women. The factor of $4!$ arises because of the number of making these pairs.

Comment: Very nicely explained. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Karla You’re welcome!